# jQuery DataTables "Apply Filters" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am using your jQuery DataTavles plugin and have managed to get most functionality required with ease. One requirement outstanding is the ability to only apply filters once an "Apply Filters" button is clicked. I have it working by iterating through each of my filters and calling fnFilter

```
$("#btnApplyFilters").click(function () {

      $("thead input[type=text]").each(function (i) {
          alert("about to add")
          oTable.fnFilter(this.value, $("thead input[type=text]").index(this));
          alert("added")
      });
      oTable.fnDraw();
  });
```

Unfortunately, the call to fnFilter causes an AJAX call to repopulate the grid. So if the user is trying to apply 3 filters, each call to fnFilter will cause a call to the server.

Is there any way I can apply all the filters in one go on a button click?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot make use of the built-in `fnFilter` to accomplish your requirement. Instead, you need to send the filter ajax request by your own (in the click handler) and redraw the table with the new data source (maybe JSON).